# Why am I seeing two different values of host.docker.internal and why the cassandra container can't bind to it

Tags: docker, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I want to run Cassandra Docker images. I am hoping that my application (running in another container) could connect to the Cassandra container. So I want to use `host.docker.internal` as domain name in both the applications.

When I start Cassandra image, I get error

```
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Unable to bind to address host.docker.internal/192.168.65.2:7000. Set listen_address in cassandra.yaml to an interface you can bind to, e.g., your private IP address on EC2
```

Why is `host.docker.internal` resolving to `192.168.65.2/7000`?. Shouldn't it be `192.168.1.12` as that is what is configured in my `etc/hosts` file on Windows 10.

```
C:\Users\manuc>ping host.docker.internal

Pinging host.docker.internal [192.168.1.12] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.12: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.12: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

I also tried explicitly specifying `192.168.1.12` when starting Cassandra images but I get similar error.

The only way I am able to start the container is by running `docker run   ca795bbd8fd7` but in this case, Cassandra listens at address `Starting listening for CQL clients on /0.0.0.0:9042 (unencrypted)..` for `cqlsh` but my other Docker application is unable to connect with it (running on the same Windows machine)

Trying to connect to Cassandra container from outside the container

```
C:\Users\manuc>cqlsh host.docker.internal 9042
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.1.12': error(10061, "Tried connecting to [('192.168.1.12', 9042)]. Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")})
C:\Users\manuc>cqlsh 0.0.0.0 9042
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'0.0.0.0': error(10049, "Tried connecting to [('0.0.0.0', 9042)]. Last error: The requested address is not valid in its context")})
```

Trying to connect my other container

```
[trace] s.d.c.CassandraConnectionManagementService - creating session with uri CassandraConnectionUri(cassandra://host.docker.internal:9042/codingjedi) and cluster name Test Cluster
[trace] s.d.c.CassandraConnectionManagementService - exception in connecting with database com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: host.docker.internal/192.168.65.2:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [host.docker.internal/192.168.65.2:9042] Cannot connect))
Oops, cannot start the server.
play.api.libs.json.JsResult$Exception: {"obj":[{"msg":["Unable to connect with database"],"args":[]}]}
```

(Though I notice that for this container as well, `docker.internal.hosts` maps to the same IP address as for Cassandra container).

Additional info. If run without `LISTENING_ADDRESS`, Cassandra exposes the following ports

```
7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp
```

Comment: Are the mechanics of `host.docker.internal` actually important to your setup?  You might ask a separate question focusing on your Cassandra setup, without any specific IP addresses or `ping` commands.  Make sure to include a [mcve] with details like how you're running the server and how you're configuring the clients.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was quite trivial. I didn't expose `9042` port when starting the `cassandra` `container`. This made things work out of the box - `docker run -p 9042:9042 image_id`